# How to use check if a pytest patched method were invoked [and with which parameters]?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

How can a *patch()* object be used to check if the method it represents had been invoked?
The following is pseudocode for the intended task

```
           from unittest.mock import patch

           # "filter" is a method on BlobFilter class
           mpatch = patch('platform.blob_reader.BlobFilter.filter')
           # other logic that should invoke that method..
           mpatch.assert_called_once()    # not supported this way, how to do it?
```

I want to use *patch* in particular because the invocation is deeply nested in our class hierarchy and trying to send/inject  mocks down that hierarchy will disrupt the codebase substantially due to adding more parameters to existing methods.

An additional goal would be to ensure the method were invoked with the correct data types. These methods exist on mocks, but I can't send in mocks to this class hierarchy at the present time.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. If you call `patch` this way, you get a patcher object, with no patching done yet. Calling `mpatch.start()` gives you the mock you can use to call the `assert_called...` methods. So what is your use case here? Where is the actual patching done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a context manager:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch('platform.blob_reader.BlobFilter.filter') as mpatch:
    # logic that should invoke that method..
    mpatch.assert_called_once()
```

Also, you could use patch as a decorator:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('platform.blob_reader.BlobFilter.filter')
def test_my_func(mpatch)
    # logic that should invoke that method..
    mpatch.assert_called_once()
```

And finally, starting and stopping the patch explicitly (the ugliest, IMHO):

```
from unittest.mock import patch

patcher = patch('platform.blob_reader.BlobFilter.filter')
mpatch = patcher.start()
# logic that should invoke that method..
mpatch.assert_called_once()
patcher.stop()
```

For checking with wich arguments it was called, have a look to the [call_args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) attribute of the mock

Comment: I like that `start` `stop` as well because in some cases i don't want a context since one is already in play

Comment: @WestCoastProjects For me, that is the ugliest way, but in some situations can be the most suited option. Don't forget to mark my answer as Accepted if it helped you :D

Comment: yea i'm actively trying out your code now.  And yes i'm trying the `with` approach as well.

Comment: Confirmed it works

Comment: For a better understanding of using mocks in python, I recommend Lisa Roach's talk at PyCon 2018: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ww1UsGZV8fQ

Comment: it's not clear to me why my original syntax did _not_ work : it actually does not even _compile_.  so i appreciate the functional code

Comment: Compile? I don't understand. Python it's an interpreted language, not a compiled one. Your original syntax did not work because you have to call `assert_called_once()` with a `Mock` object, and `patch()` just returns the context, not a `Mock`. When you activate it using `start()`, it returns the `Mock` object with which you can make the assertions. In my examples, `mpatch` is a Mock. In yours, it doesn't.

Comment: by 'compile' i mean: `pycharm` flags the code as incorrect and when interpreted it will fail.  I don't actually need a lecture on it being an interpreted language but when we have an IDE that will fast-forward the interpreter process we get the same result.

Your second comment about invoking the `start()` does however bring up something I missed: I should have placed a type-hint on the return value of the patch() and start() to then allow `pycharm` to properly do the interpreter fast-forward and tell me correctly or not if the code will encounter errors when run

Comment: I don't know why adding type hints is needed. I've made a test and pycharm detects successfully that calling `patch` returns a `mock._patch` class object. And that calling `start` on that object returns a `MagicMock`

Comment: `pycharm` was not detecting in my case, so am uncertain of the difference in circumstances.  i had to rewrite the tests for an unrelated reason and will get back when i have a similar snippet